# Passing and storing a reference to an object field to another object without reflection

Tags: c#

In Lua, since objects are usually implemented as hashtables (like in JS), I can write a tweening function with the following signature (or, rather, it has already been written):

`timer.tween(delay_in_s, object, table_of_target_values, algorithm)`

and `timer.tween` will be able to access `object` fields enumerated in the `table_of_target_values` to save their initial values. `timer.update` will then be able to also reference them and set their values.

Is there a way to save a reference to a class field in C# if it's a value type? I know that you can't pass properties by reference (while you can in VB.NET), but fields are okay. But how can you save it for later use by other methods without using reflection?

One workaround is passing a setter closure instead of the object itself, so the signature looks like this:

`Timer.Tween<T>(double delay, T initialValue, T targetValue, Action<T> setter, Algorithm algorithm)`

and calling it like this:

`Timer.Tween(delay, obj.fld, targetValue, (x)=>obj.fld=x, Algorithm.Linear);`

Is it the only option?

EDIT: to clarify my case, there's `Timer.Update(double delta)` that updates all variables referenced in `Timer.Tween()` calls until they reach their target value, it's not just the question of passing a reference to `Timer.Tween()`.

Comment: Do you mean call by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go ahead with my closure approach and it doesn't look that bad, I'd even say it looks quite elegant.

```
/// <summary>
/// A static class that manages all active tweens.
/// </summary>
public abstract class Tween
{
    private static HashSet<Tween> tweens = new HashSet<Tween>();

    private Tween() {}

    public static void Add<T>(double delay, T initialValue, T targetValue, Action<T> setter, Algorithm algorithm, Action onCompletion)
    {
        var t = new TweenImpl<T>(delay, initialValue, targetValue, setter, algorithm, onCompletion);
        tweens.Add(t);
    }

    public static void Update(double delta)
    {
        var toRemove = new List<Tween>();
        foreach (var t in tweens) {
            if (t.UpdateTween(delta)) {
                toRemove.Add(t);
            }
        }
        foreach (var t in toRemove) {
            tweens.Remove(t);
        }
    }

    internal abstract bool UpdateTween(double delta);

    /// <summary>
    /// A class that represents tweens.
    /// </summary>
    private class TweenImpl<T> : Tween
    {
        private double delay;
        private double accumulatedDelta;
        private T initialValue;
        private T valueRange;
        private Action<T> setter;
        private Algorithm algorithm;
        private Action onCompletion;

        internal TweenImpl(double delay, T initialValue, T targetValue, Action<T> setter, Algorithm algorithm, Action onCompletion)
        {
            this.delay = delay;
            this.initialValue = initialValue;
            this.valueRange = Operator.Subtract(targetValue, initialValue);
            this.setter = setter;
            this.algorithm = algorithm;
            this.onCompletion = onCompletion;
            this.accumulatedDelta = 0.0;
            this.setter.Invoke(this.initialValue);
        }

        internal override bool UpdateTween(double delta) {
            var toRemove = false;
            this.accumulatedDelta += delta;
            if (this.accumulatedDelta >= this.delay){
                this.accumulatedDelta = this.delay;
                toRemove = true;
            }
            var percentage = (double)this.accumulatedDelta/this.delay;
            percentage = this.algorithm.Adjust(percentage);
            var result = Operator.AddAlternative(this.initialValue, Operator.MultiplyAlternative(percentage, this.valueRange));
            this.setter.Invoke(result);
            if (toRemove) {
                this.onCompletion.Invoke();
            }
            return toRemove;
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem I have encountered is that you cannot restrict the T to numeric types, so I used [MiscUtil by John Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil) to generate lambdas at runtime. This, of course, means the program will crash if someone tries to tween a string, but this is something I am willing to live with.

You call it like this (I tested this on a progress bar):

```
Tween.Add(15.0, prgTest.Minimum, prgTest.Maximum, x=>prgTest.Value=x, Algorithm.Linear, ()=>{
                            running = false;
                            MessageBox.Show("Done");
                         });
```

And then simply call

```
Tween.Update(delta);
```

at the top of the update loop to automatically tween your variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use call by reference in C# by using the `ref` keyword:

```
public void Swap(ref int a, ref int b) 
{
    int c = b;
    b = a;
    a = c;
}

public void DoSwap()
{
   int x = 1;
   int y = 2;
   Console.WriteLine(x + " "  + y); // should write 1 2
   Swap(ref x, ref y);
   Console.WriteLine(x + " "  + y); // should write 2 1
}
```

Now, just because you CAN do this doesn't mean you SHOULD. Typically you should try to adapt to the common idioms of the language and embrace those rather than through `ref` into just about every method.

Comment: Hi. Calling by reference is something I am aware of, but storing this reference in the object is another thing. In my example, there's another method `Tween.Update` that should be able to modify the same variable when called by an event loop.

Comment: @Alexey are you wanting something like a global variable that can be updated at any time?

Comment: No, let me clarify the idea. Most game engines have a single procedure that is repeatedly called by the engine. This means that if you want some value to change smoothly, you have to calculate its value at every step. You also don't want to simply lerp the value, since it looks bad on screen, so you use other functions that go from 0 to 1 to calculate intermediate steps.
A tweening (or easing) function encapsulates this behavior. You register something like menu screen coordinates via one function, and by calling the other function in the game loop you smoothly change all registered variables.

Comment: @Alexey Ok that makes more sense, thank you. What is wrong with creating a class that encapsulates all of that data and then pass that class around? The value types are passed by reference by default and that lets you modify the class in any method that takes it as a parameter.

Comment: The problem is that solution is not general enough. I might want to change the alpha of the sprite from 255 to 0 in one place, top of another sprite from 750 to 800 in another place, and volume of the music from 100 to 0 in the third. Do I have to wrap each field of each object in a new SettableValue<> object? What if I have to change an object of a class I can't modify? I guess my closure solution is the best.

Comment: @Alexey I think you need to step back and look at your architecture again. However, if you have a class that has an int on it and you pass the class in, you can modify that int and it will change the int member of the class. You don't need SettableValue<>, as far as I can see.

Comment: yes, I can pass the class in, but how can I pass which int I want to change? If I have something like `class Frame {int Top, Left;}`, how can I tell the method if I want to change Top or Left when I later call another method?

Comment: @Alexey You could use reflection to get the member name of the class that you want to modify. You could use an Enum to dictate which value would need to be changed. You could use separate methods indicating which value needs to be changed.